# Centos 7 with libvirt, Kvm and balloon consumes 100% cpu on all versions of windows

Tags: centos, windows-server-2008-r2, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

Windows works perfectly, but the balloon does not work, after setting the min and max memory and activating the BLNSVR service, windows starts to consume 100% CPU. If put Min and max memory equal the CPU consumption returns to normal and if keep minimum memory different from maximum and disable the service BLNSVR the CPU also returns to normal operation. Tested on default libvirt and KVM of CentOs 7 and Epel-release and alternative version libvirt 3.4 and QEMU 2.9. My Kernel is 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.

My libvirt is:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
    <name>win2008r2</name>
    <uuid>1190af9e-cd02-47d2-8bb4-6b9ce6d7cdfc</uuid>
    <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
    <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
    <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
    <os>
        <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.9'>hvm</type>
        <boot dev='hd'/>
    </os>
    <features>
        <acpi/>
        <apic/>
        <hyperv>
            <relaxed state='on'/>
            <vapic state='on'/>
            <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
        </hyperv>
        <vmport state='off'/>
    </features>
    <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
        <model fallback='allow'>kvm64</model>
        <topology sockets='2' cores='4' threads='1'/>
    </cpu>
    <clock offset='localtime'>
        <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
        <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
        <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
        <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
    </clock>
    <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
    <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
    <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
    <pm>
        <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
        <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
    </pm>
    <devices>
        <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
        <disk type='file' device='disk'>
            <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
            <source file='/home/kvm/win2008r2.qcow2'/>
            <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
        </disk>
        <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
            <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
            <source file='/home/iso/virtio-win.iso'/>
            <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
            <readonly/>
            <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
        </disk>
        <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
        </controller>
        <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
            <master startport='0'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
        </controller>
        <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
            <master startport='2'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
        </controller>
        <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
            <master startport='4'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
        </controller>
        <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
        <controller type='ide' index='0'>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
        </controller>
        <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
        </controller>
        <interface type='direct'>
            <mac address='52:54:00:75:df:96'/>
            <source dev='eno2.999' mode='bridge'/>
            <model type='virtio'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
        </interface>
        <serial type='pty'>
            <target port='0'/>
        </serial>
        <console type='pty'>
            <target type='serial' port='0'/>
        </console>
        <channel type='spicevmc'>
            <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
            <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
        </channel>
        <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
            <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
        </input>
        <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
        <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
        <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
            <listen type='address'/>
            <image compression='off'/>
        </graphics>
        <sound model='ich6'>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
        </sound>
        <video>
            <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
        </video>
        <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
            <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
        </redirdev>
        <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
            <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
        </redirdev>
        <memballoon model='virtio'>
            <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
        </memballoon>
    </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: I don't have installed anything than windows default installation and virtio software. Balloon apparently works but 100% CPU all time.